# Is there a Python tkinter function that makes a drawing’s coords on a certain ratio on the canvas widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I’m a first timer at tkinter(python) and what I want to do is to make a line of text stay on the same coords ratio on the canvas. For example, I want a line of text to stay in the middle. Is there any tkinter text parameters that make it stay in a certain ratio without running a while loop? I want minimal time complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GUI can have a function bound to the Canvas `<Configure>` event that fires whenever the Canvas changes size. A simple example below.

There is also a `Canvas.scale` method which will change the location and size of canvas objects.  Text may move but will not change size.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# Create a canvas that will change size with the root window.
canvas = tk.Canvas( root, width = 600, height = 400, borderwidth = 2, 
    relief = tk.SOLID )
canvas.grid( sticky = 'nsew', padx = 5, pady = 5 )

root.grid_columnconfigure( 0, weight = 1 )
root.grid_rowconfigure( 0, weight = 1 )

text = canvas.create_text( 50, 50, text = 'Test Text' )

def on_canvas_config( event ):
    """  This is bound to the canvas <Configure> event.
         It executes when the canvas changes size.
         The event is an object that contains the new width and height.
    """
    x = max( 25, event.width  // 2 )      # x >= 25
    y = max( 12, event.height // 8 )      # y >= 12
    canvas.coords( text, x, y )           # Set the canvas coordinates

canvas.bind( '<Configure>', on_canvas_config )

root.mainloop()
```

The `on_canvas_configure` function can be written to amend the coords of any objects in the Canvas to meet your requirements.  I've never tried to use the `Canvas.scale` method but this may be worth exploring if there are many objects to reposition on the canvas.

Comment: @JWS I assume you meant `grid`.  It's an alternative geometry manager to pack.   Using the `sticky` parameter as `nsew` means the widget sticks to all 4 sides of the containing cell and expands or contracts as the cell changes size.